# Launching Eclipse on Linux crashed Exceed

Tags: eclipse, exceed

Although this Luna version of Eclipse is old, it is the only one that even attempts to launch. 
The OS doesn't have the required files needed by the newer versions of Eclipse.

Putty is on the Windows machine with Exceed running to connect to the Linux machine were Eclipse attemts to get launched.

It is important to note that Eclipse starts. I am even able to select my Project. 
The next screen attempts to launch but then Eclipse and Exceed goes away.

```
> ./eclipse
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  
Will retry after the state location is initialized.
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config file: home/user1/workspace\Project1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration/logback.1.5.1.20150109-1820.xml
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback
Eclipse: Fatal IO error 0 (Success) on X server localhost:11.0.
PuTTY X11 proxy: unable to connect to forwarded X server: Network error: Connection refused
Eclipse: Cannot open display:
Eclipse:
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /home/user1/EclipseJava/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.                                                                                                                                     3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /home/user1/EclipseJava/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.4 .2.v20150204-1700/splash.bmp
-launcher /home/user1/EclipseJava/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/user1/EclipseJava/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equin ox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316/eclipse_1607.so
-startup /home/user1/EclipseJava/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 57fc000b
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /home/user1/EclipseJava/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
```

Here is the Java Version.

```
> java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
```

Usually the X11 failure occurs if X11 forwarding is not on, but as stated above, it does indeed launch. 
It is possible the X11 failure is due to Exceed going a way and a postmortem error.

That fact that Eclipse does launch and crashes afterward makes me wonder if some default setting needs to change.

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: "PuTTY X11 proxy: unable to connect to forwarded X server: Network error: Connection refused" looks like the important message - the connection attempt is being rejected

Comment: Would that be an Eclipse setting because it works fine with other applications?